# Get all live checkins or push event from github

Tags: github, github-api

Is there any api where I can get live commits of public event, i.e get the commit url as and when the user pushes to github.I tried github.com/timeline but it only gives me 30 urls at a time and no pagination.

I dont want to get any specific user or repo commits, I wish to get all the commits as and when its pushed.

Thanks

Comment: All commits for all github projects?

Comment: Yes .But not the ones that are already pushed . I would like to get new ones that are getting pushed every second, like RSS feed . The existing RSS feed only gives 30 events per request.

Comment: JFYI, this is called a "firehose" and twitter, for example, charges a shit ton of money for access to theirs. :)